# How can I create a collage of randomly sized overlapping polygons and randomly fill (to an extent) with gradients? (Illustrator)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, script

I am trying to learn how to make something exactly like this from scratch:
[image]

Comment: [Low Poly art](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+make+low-+poly+art+in+Illustrator&oq=how+to+make+low-+poly+art+in+Illustrator&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.6718j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) -- You may simply be unfamiliar with the proper term to search.

Answer (score 0):

I think they might all have the same type of gradient (or maybe a couple of variants) and four different colours. It just looks like more due to the effects of layering. Try to layer a few of these shapes on top of each other and then select all and fiddle with the transparency setting to see if it looks like your example.